# Why is this element not being fetched from firestore?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

Code: (I'm 99% sure the issue is in the mounted method)

```
  <div class="taskManager">
    <FilterNav @filterChange="current = $event" 
    :current="current"/>
    <div class="tasks">
      <div v-if="tasks.length">
        <div v-for="task in filterTasks" :key="task.id">
          <SingleTask :task="task" @delete="handleDelete"
          @complete="handleComplete"/>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <TasksNavbar/>
  <router-view/>
</template>
<script>
import TasksNavbar from '../components/TasksNavbar.vue'
import SingleTask from '../components/SingleTask.vue'
import FilterNav from '../components/TaskFilterNav.vue'
import Navbar from '../components/Navbar.vue'
import { computed } from 'vue'
import firebase from 'firebase/app'
import 'firebase/auth'
import 'firebase/firestore'
export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: { SingleTask, TasksNavbar, FilterNav, Navbar},
  data() {
    return {
      tasks: [],
      current: 'all'
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)
    docRef.get("tasks").then(function(task){
      if(task.exists){
        this.tasks.push(task.data())
      }
    }).catch(function(err){
      console.log(err.message)
    })
  },
```

File Structure:
Collection: users -> documents of users with the name of the document being the user id -> an array of tasks as a field with tasks inside of it

Tasks are being saved to firestore properly, but it is not fetching them correctly.

Comment: "it is not fetching them correctly" is hard to help with. What happens if you step through the code line by line in a debugger? Which line doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen docRef.get("tasks").forEach(function(task){
      if(task.exists){
        this.tasks.push(task.data())
      } those lines

Answer (score 1):

---

While I was writing the answer you edited your question from

```
docRef.get("tasks").forEach(...)
```

to

```
docRef.get("tasks").then(...)
```

but it doesn't change the answer's content.

---

`docRef` is a [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) and its `get()` method is **asynchronous** and returns a `DocumentSnapshot`. You are mixing up this method with the [`get()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot#get) method of the `DocumentSnapshot` (which is not asynchronous btw).

You need to do as follows:

```
var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid)

docRef.get().then(doc => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        const tasksArray = doc.get("tasks");
        tasksArray.forEach(...);
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
}).catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
});
```

---

In addition, as explained [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#get_the_currently_signed-in_user), you should note that `firebase.auth().currentUser.uid` may return `null` because the object returned by  `firebase.auth()` may be in an intermediate state, such as initialization.

You need to ensure that `firebase.auth().currentUser` is not null.

Depending on your exact sign-in flow, you may need to put the code in your Vue.js `mounted` hook in an `onAuthStateChanged` observer:

```
mounted() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
      if (user) {
        // Put your code here => user is not null
        var docRef = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(user.uid)
    
        docRef.get().then(doc => {...});
        // ....

       }
    });
}
```